# Dynamic Morris Line string conversion ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, morris.js

I am trying to do Morris Line Chart with data from mysql using php.. but I am getting Array to string conversion error in my console when I debug. Below is my code

```
       <?php

            try { $stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT register_date FROM members  ");
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
             catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
                    }


                $chart_data = array(); // define array

                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $signup = date('F d Y ', strtotime($row["register_date"]));

                    $chart_data .= "{ date: '" .$signup. "' },";

                    }

        ?>

        <script type="application/javascript">

            Morris.Line({
                    element: 'signups',  // div id
                    data: [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
                    xkey: 'date',
                    ykeys: 'date',
                    lables: 'sigups',
                    hidehover: 'auto' 


                });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$chart_data` contains **invalid json**.

Please, do not invent the wheel and use `json_encode`:

```
$chart_data = array(); // define array
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $signup = date('F d Y ', strtotime($row["register_date"]));
    $chart_data[] = ['date' => $signup];
}
```

js-part:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'signups',  // div id
    data: <?php echo json_encode($chart_data); ?>,
    xkey: 'date',
    ykeys: 'date',
    lables: 'sigups',
    hidehover: 'auto' 
});
```

Comment: if I echo json_encode ($chart_data). I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: Simple search proposes this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601985/morris-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined

Comment: Also make sure that you __removed__ quotes around `<?php echo json_encode($chart_data); ?>`

Comment: this is the error...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.. and it is coming from the $chart_data